# How to concatenate string values from three different aliases and find the min value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008. I have to find the MIN of type string among three possible string values. I know how to do it if the values are from a single column of a table. In my case, it comes from three different aliases.

This is part of the SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerId,
    leaseType = (CASE 
                    WHEN MIN(CONCAT(L1.LeaseType, L2.LeaseType, L3.LeaseType)) = 'T' 
                       THEN 'Temporary' 
                    WHEN MIN(CONCAT(L1.LeaseType, L2.LeaseType, L3.LeaseType)) = 'P' 
                       THEN 'Permanant'  
                    WHEN MIN(CONCAT(L1.LeaseType, L2.LeaseType, L3.LeaseType)) = 'U'  
                       THEN 'Unknown' 
                    ELSE '' 
                 END)
FROM
    Customer
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CustomerId, LeaseType 
     FROM
         Lease 
     WHERE
         LeaseType  = 'T') L1 ON L1.CustomerId  = c.CustomerId  
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CustomerId, LeaseType  
     FROM
         Lease 
     WHERE
         LeaseType = 'P') L2 ON L2.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CustomerId, LeaseType  
     FROM
         Lease 
     WHERE
         LeaseType  = 'U') L3 ON L3.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
WHERE 
    CustomerId > 10000
```

However, that query doesn't work. Among other errors, it also throws

> 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!  It really is not obvious what strings you want the minimum of.

Comment: The three possible values are "T", "P" or "U"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Answer (score 1):

If you want the "minimum" of the lease type, you can use `apply`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM Customer c JOIN
     Lease lt
     ON lt.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND
        lt.LeaseType  = 'T' JOIN
     Lease lp
     ON lp.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND
        lp.LeaseType  = 'P' JOIN
     Lease lu
     ON lu.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND
        lu.LeaseType  = 'U' CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MIN(v.LeaseType) as LeaseType
      FROM (VALUES (lt.LeaseType), (lp.LeaseType), (lu.LeaseType)
     ) v(LeaseType)
```

This answers the question that you have asked.  I doubt it does anything useful, though, because it will always return 'P'.  Why?  All the `JOIN`s are inner joins, so they require a match.  The `LeaseType` is used in the `JOIN` condition, so a match is required.  This only matches customers that have all three.

I can speculate that you might want outer joins.  Instead of speculating, though, it would be better for you to ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this leads me in the right direction. If one of the value happens to be null, is there any way I could ignore the null and find the min value of the non-null values only? Thanks!

Comment: @Massey . . . `min()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: The Lease table can have three possible rows for a given CustomerId. So for each row in the Customer table the lease table can have a row LeaseType = "T" and LeaseType = "P" and LeaseType = "U". In that case, LeaseType should be "Permanent". If the Lease table had rows corresponding to only "T" and "U", then the LeaseType should return "Temporary".

Comment: Hi Gordon, when I tried your query I am getting incorrect syntax near 'v' error.